# compile and deploy individual components in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

Is it possible to compile an individual component in AOSP (Android Open Source Project), say the lock screen component, and just deploy that component to the phone?

I am making modifications to the source code of AOSP and wonder if I need to compile the entire AOSP and flash it to the phone everytime I change it. That would be slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Basically, for building of a separate module you need to use utils defined in `envsetup.sh` file:

- `m`:       Makes from the top of the tree.
- `mm`:      Builds all of the modules in the current directory.
- `mmm`:     Builds all of the modules in the supplied directories.

After the first time you've flashed your device with your modifications, for synchronization you can use the following sequence of commands:

1. `adb remount` - mounts system image as read-write
2. `adb sync` - synchronize data on system and data partition